# Navigating to item in Xamarin.Forms from a view that has a custom renderer causes blank black/white screen in iOS

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, prism

When navigating to an item in a Flyout menu from a view that contains a custom renderer, the screen turns into blank black/white screen where the white was the flyout menu, and the black is the detail (see attached). We are using Prism navigation to navigate via the flyout menu.

[Screenshot of blank black and white sections](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gqqNW.png)

This happens only in iOS.

Expected behavior was to navigate to a different screen/view but, instead, it gave us what you see in the screenshot above. In addition, we have to force-close the app because we get stuck.

At first, we thought that it was a Flyout issue but it appears to be a navigation issue.

Anybody know what may be causing this anomalous behavior?

Comment: Please read [ask] before posting.  You haven't asked a question or posted any code illustrating what you are doing.

Comment: Thanks; added a question at the bottom of our (original) post.

Comment: You should add code for the custom renderer for iOS. Did you look at the debug console for error messages? It's hard to say what is happening but most likely cause would be an exception happening on the iOS renderer. Does it render if you display the page without navigation?